# Installshield Automation Interface Reference create folder

Tags: installshield

I want to add patch configuration by installshield Automation 
is it possible ?
I dont find any references to this subject 
could you reference me or give me some directs how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the automation interface,  you can do it as follows

%INSTALLSHIELD_SABUILD_FOLDER%\System\IsCmdBld.exe -p "%PATH_TO_ISM_FILE%\IShield.ism" -patch_config "PatchConfigurationName"
Where PatchConfigurationName is the name under Meda -> Patch Design -> PatchConfigurationName

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply! I'm sorry I was not understandable.
I was asked to give a end to end solution, once I build some patc in the end I will get the patch installer without hand involving .
so I'm trying to automate all I done manually ,such as create folder and configure all Patch Design -> Patch ConfigurationName
Regards
Shavit